# No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList to a known managed provider native type

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to store GridView values into a database but i keep getting error:

> No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList to a known managed provider native type.

Interface: The Attendance column is a template I inserted into the grid view

[image: X]

Below is my code c#:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GVAttend.Rows.Count; i++) {
    SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection();
    Con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Data;Integrated Security=True";

    String query2 = "Insert into Attendance(Student_ID, Course_Code, Date, Status, Student_Name, Att_by) Values(@Stu_ID ,@Course_Code ,@Date ,@Status ,@Stu_Name ,@Attby)";
    SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(query2, Con);

    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stu_ID", GVAttend.Rows[i].Cells[0].ToString());
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Course_Code", DropCourse.SelectedItem.Text);
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date.GetDateTimeFormats()[8].ToString());
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stu_Name", GVAttend.Rows[i].Cells[1].ToString());
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", GVAttend.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("DropAtt") as DropDownList);
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Attby", Session["Username"].ToString());

    Con.Open();
    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    Con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", GVAttend.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("DropAtt") as DropDownList);
```

looks fishy

you should get selected value from dropdownlist

```
 Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", (GVAttend.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("DropAtt") as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gaurav, I tried your code and got this message:
     String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: its your data type in sqlserver which is causing problem .What data type you are using for @Status column in sqlserver . Hope you are using varchar.

Comment: @Status varchar(30)

Answer (score 1):

Searching a control by column index is very fragile. It will throw run-time exception if you accidentally move columns.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GVAttend.Rows)
{
    ...
    var dropAtt = row.FindControl("DropAtt") as DropDownList;
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", dropAtt.SelectedValue);    
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Win, I am yet to try your code because i got an error with the "row".FindControl. Any suggestions?

Comment: In which event did you place the above code? Could you post the exception message?

Comment: The code is inside 
     protected void btnaddatt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
        var DropAtt = row.FindControl("DropAtt") as DropDownList;
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", DropAtt.SelectedValue);

It says the name "row" does not exist in the current context.

Comment: You need to iterate `GVAttend.Rows` and get `GridViewRow` object. Please look at my answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I can't believe i missed that.  I still can't execute the query. Am getting this message: "String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated". Any ideas please...

Comment: Do you need me to share how my code looks like now?

Comment: The error message basically said inserted text is larger than the column size. Solution is to increase the column size or truncate the input text.

Comment: Done. I noticed my Data get duplicated after execution, so i put a 'break' and it stopped, but the Attendance column stores only one value 'Present' for all names.